# Can't create an object from an Ajax view

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

**Edit**: The problem was solved, now I've another problem. The data variable returns nothing when it should return "OK" or "EXISTS".

I have a template with an overlay effect. The income.html template has a form and a button "Add a new category", when you click on it a new window is displayed(overlay effect) with a tiny form. I don't know why, but the category doesn't get created. It seems I've got some errors in the html script but I can't identify them.

income.html:

```
(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#new_cat").live("click", ( function() {      
    var cat_name = $("#nc").val();
    if (cat_name) {
        $.get("/cashflow/new_cat/0/", { name: cat_name, account: {{ account }} },
          function(data){
            if (data == "OK") {
                $("#id_category").val(cat_name);
            }
            if (data == "EXISTS") {
                var error = "The category already exists";
                alert(error);
            }
          });
    }
    else {
         var error = "Please enter a name";
         alert(error);
    }
}))  
});
</script>
...

<form>{% csrf_token %}
       <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" id="nc" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="new_cat" />
</form>
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def income(request, account_name): 
    account = account_name
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            income = form.save(commit=False)
            income.type = 0
            income.account = Account.objects.get(
                            name = account_name,
                            user = request.user)
            income.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            income.category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            income.save()
            uri = ("/cashflow/account/%s") % str(account_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(uri)

    else:
        form = TransForm(user=request.user)

    context = {
          'TransForm': form,
          'type': '0',
          'account': account, 
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'cashflow/income.html',
        context,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )

def new_cat(request, tipo):
    if request.method == u'GET':
        GET = request.GET
        if GET.has_key(u'name'):
            name = request.GET[u'name']
            account = request.GET[u'account']
            c = Category.objects.filter(namee=name, account=account)
            if c:
                s = "EXISTS"
            else:
                c = Category(name = name, user = request.user, 
                        type = type, account = account)
                c.save()
                s = "OK"

    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Comment: If you can post a demo reproducing the problem that would be a help; I'd suggest [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new_cat view (I think tipo equals type).

Beside that, I guess the error is here:

```
account = request.GET[u'account']
c = Category.objects.filter(name=name, account=account)
```

account is a unicode string but you need an account instance to filter the categories. Something like this should work fine:

```
account_st = request.GET[u'account']
account = Account.objects.get(name=account_st)
c = Category.objects.filter(name=name, account=account)
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks a bit dodgy:

```
{ name: cat_name, account: {{ account }} }
```

Remember that this is being rendered inside a Javascript block. `cat_name` is a JS variable, so will be evaluated correctly. But `{{ account }}` renders to a *string*, so as far as the JS is concerned it is a literal. So it needs to be in quotes:

```
{ name: cat_name, account: "{{ account }}" }
```